# Chromium/WhatsApp Web is removing forward slashes when submitting text through Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, whatsapp

I am sending messages through WhatsApp Web using Selenium. The program works fine on my Mac but when I run it on a Raspberry Pi the forward slashes are being removed by either Chromium or WhatsApp.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data") #this is needed to stop WhatsApp asking for QR code verification
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='REMOVED']").click() #change REMOVED to phone number or group chat name
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys('Here is the news: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]/button/span').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

The message being sent looks like this:

Here is the news: https:[www.bbc.co.uknews](http://www.bbc.co.uknews)

For an unknown reason the forward slashes are being removed. If I manually copy/paste into WhatsApp Webb the forward slashes are not removed. It is only when they are entered through the Python script.

I have updated Chromium and running Version 86.0.4240.197 (Official Build) Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10 (32-bit)

My ChromeDriver is version 86.0.4240.197 also.

Comment: I am sure though, have u tried using raw string like r'this is a string' ?

Comment: @epsi95 - I just tried a raw string and the forward slashes were still removed.

Comment: i tried now in windows10 it works fine

Comment: @PDHide - it works fine on my Mac, too. It's Raspberry Pi/Linux I'm having the difficulty with.

Comment: what happens when you try to print it instead of sendkeys still the front slash is missing ?

Comment: @PDHide No, it prints correctly in Thonny.

Comment: It also happens using Selenium on NodeJS

Comment: I facing the same issue but to another web application, any solution so far?

Comment: I couldn't resolve the problem. I switched to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys(
    '\u0048\u0065\u0072\u0065\u0020\u0069\u0073\u0020\u0074\u0068\u0065\u0020\u006e\u0065\u0077\u0073\u003a\u0020\u0068\u0074\u0074\u0070\u0073\u003a\u002f\u002f\u0077\u0077\u0077\u002e\u0062\u0062\u0063\u002e\u0063\u006f\u002e\u0075\u006b\u002f\u006e\u0065\u0077\u0073')
```

Could you try printing with unicode and see whats happening

Comment: Ran the code again with the unicode. No change. Still sending "Here is the news: https:www.bbc.co.uknews"

Comment: what if you send //// four front slash

Comment: I just tried r'////???!!!""@@@@####~~~~|||' to see if it affects any other characters. This was the output in WhatsApp ???!!!""@@@@####~~~~|||

Comment: are you able to ssend forward slah manually to whatsapp web in that os ?

Comment: is the issue specific to whqtsapp ui or any other website?

Comment: If I copy/paste a link to WhatsApp it works ok and the forward slashes aren't removed. I can also type the forward slashes into WhatsApp without an issue. The problem only occurs when I use my Python Script to .send_keys with a forward slash. I've not had the Pi very long but haven't noticed an issue in any other programme.